# Is "gobload" a valid word?

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word

This word just came naturally to me while writing some prose. Will it be understood by English speakers/readers?

Comment: First hit on google right now is this question, so I'm guessing it's not that common :)

Comment: @Benjol:  Well that and I imagine that StackExchange questions get quite a bit of weight by Google PageRank.  Hopefully more weight than those ridiculous ExpertsExchange _(ExpertSexChange?)_ entries.

Comment: *Gobload* is an awesome word. It gets your point across fast. "Tonight, we're going out to pizza. I'm gonna order mine with a gobload of cheese!"

Comment: It sounds like a euphemism for _shitload_, so be careful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not without a hyphen: *gob-load*. Without the hyphen, I parsed it as "go bload", which of course makes no sense. However, I expect that most native speakers of English will understand "gob-load".

Comment: Makes perfect sense to us Brits

Comment: There's hod-load as well.

Comment: Don't forget buttload